# char and int Concatenation

Tags: java, char, integer, logic, concatenation

series: A2, C4, D6, E8, G10, H12, I14, J16, K18, M20,....

I have tried this....

```
public class test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        
        int a=2;
        char ch = 'A';
        
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
            
            System.out.print(ch+Integer.toString(a));
            a+=2;

            if(a==4){
                ch++;
            }

            ch++;
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

input: 10
output: A2 C4 D6 E8 F10 G12 H14 I16 J18 K20 L22
expected output: A2 C4 D6 E8 G10 H12 I14 J16 K18 M20

I tried different statements in 'if' but I didn't get the expected output. Can anyone help me with the logic?

Comment: Why is `B` excluded from your result? And why are `L & F` not part of the output in the first example, but they are in the second example?

Comment: Is your goal to skip an alphabetical character by following this rule? Rule: print 1 character - skip - print 3 characters - skip - print 5 characters... and so on (each time print +2 consecutive characters). Also, what should happen if `n` is so big that all the alphabetical uppercase characters have already been printed?

Comment: the rule is correct and do it till alphabetical uppercase characters i.e., n<=26.

Answer (score 0):

In here what need to do is , print 1 character then 3 characters then 5 characters like so, we need to skip the characters at `2*skipTimes-1`

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int a=2;
    int skipFactor = 0;
    int skipTimes = 0;
    char ch = 'A';

    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        System.out.print(ch+Integer.toString(a)+" ");
        a+=2;
        ch++;

        if(i==skipFactor){
            skipTimes+=1;
            skipFactor+=Math.pow(2,skipTimes)+1;
            ch++;
        }
    }
}
```

and output will be,
`A2 C4 D6 E8 G10 H12 I14 J16 K18 M20 N22`

Comment: @Nicola `'n` is the no of items that needs to print.